# Dynamically create DataGridView columns based on number of records in database table in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, variables, dynamic, datagridview

I'm looking for a way to generate columns in my DataGridView for certain ECTypes based on how many ECTypes are in the ECType table, in my database.

All I am really looking for is to create the variables, I'm quite confident I know how to approach the creation of the DataGridView once I have dynamically generated the variables.

Here is my creation code currently:

```
Private Sub buildIndividualStores()
    Dim stores As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Dim split As New NumericUpDownColumn ' Classes for the custom control are defined at the bottom of the page.
    Dim value As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

    Dim ecList As New ArrayList
    For Each ec As ECType In SQL.getECTypes
        ecList.Add(ec)
    Next

    Dim handling As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Dim check As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
End Sub
```

For context, there are currently three EC Types in the table, although, I want to ensure my application is scalable for future EC Types.

I have the objects as you can see in the loop, but how do I use these objects to generate DataGridViewTextBoxColumns? I've done some research on the Dictionary class, but I fail to see how that would solve my dilemma, as I can not anticipate the number of objects that I will have.

Can it be done so I have these dynamic variables, and am able to reference them?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to store objects of multiple different types in a single data structure? Also you want to be able to access a dynamically created variable by its name?

Comment: Also just a suggestion, why don't you use a SQL or LINQ query to get only the data you want and then bind it to your data grid? Do you specifically want to add the data manually?

Comment: No, ECType is just the name of the table. ECTypeID, ECTypeName, ECTypeCode. I need to generate DataGridView columns for each record with a name that is equal to ECTypeName. And I am using SQL to get the specific data. Nothing should be entered manually.

Comment: If it's a single table with three columns, please clarify why what you want to do can't be done simply by binding your table to a data grid with a sqldatasource and by using tableadapters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171892.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1